# Wordpress update custom fields ACF programmatically when posts are imported

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I am faced with a singular issue.

I have a plugin that syncs the RSS feed to posts (of category *episode*) in wordpress.

This plugin does not retrieve the duration of the episode so I thought I would do it myself, the plugin updates 2 episodes a month so not too much stress.

Took me hours to put together the following code in my theme's *functions.php*.

Every episode post has ACF Custom fields attached with duration/shownotes etc., so the idea is once the importer fetches the monthly episode, this would get the duration automatically and populate the relative ACF Field.

Here's the code:

```
function get_stream_from_audio_src($string){

    preg_match_all('#\bhttps?://[^\s()<>]+(?:\([\w\d]+\)|([^[:punct:]\s]|/))#', $string, $match);
    $stream_url = substr($match[0][0], 0, strpos($match[0][0], "mp3")+3);

    return $stream_url;
}

function run_after_saving_episode( $post ) {

    global $post;

    if (empty(get_post_meta($post->ID, 'duration', true))) {
        $clean_url = get_stream_from_audio_src(get_post_meta($post->ID, 'stream_id', true));
        $duration = get_MP3_Duration($clean_url);
        update_post_meta($post->ID, 'duration', $duration);
    }
}

add_action( 'acf/save_post', 'run_after_saving_episode',25,1 );
```

All works fine if I save / update manually in the admin, but the episode importer doesn't seem to trigger acf/save_post.

Am I missing something?

Thanks y'all!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check if there is an action in the RSS importer from where you can call your own functin `run_after_saving_episode`.

```
<?php

add_action( PODCAST_IMPORTER_SECONDLINE_ALIAS . '_feed_item_imported', function( $feed_item_class ) {
    // Your logic here to get your $duration

    // Sanitzie the data
    $duration = podcast_importer_secondline_sanitize_feed_value( $duration );

    // Update the post meta
    update_post_meta( $feed_item_class->current_post_id, 'duration', $duration);
});
```

https://plugins.trac.wordpress.org/browser/podcast-importer-secondline/trunk/app/Helper/Importer/FeedItem.php#L227

There are a bunch of variables available in the `$feed_item_class`, like `$feed_item_class->audio_url` and other which you might can use and find here above in the `__construct()` https://plugins.trac.wordpress.org/browser/podcast-importer-secondline/trunk/app/Helper/Importer/FeedItem.php#L47

Remember to replace `$this` with `$feed_item_class` in your PHP code.

Comment: Podcast Importer and Podcast Importer Pro by SecondLine.
naturally I don't want to touch the source files from the dev as they get updated.
Does this help?

Comment: No worries, no need to change the code in the plugin. I updated the anwser to use the correct action from the plugin.

Comment: Wow thanks a lot for the effort, I will try it out!

Comment: That worked a treat JMSLBAM!
I just added $duration = $feed_item_class->duration; and job done!

Comment: Whoop whoop, happy to hear and happy to help! Have a good day 

Comment: Adding to this now I'd like to parse the imported post when the plug in has finished.
To do that I added

 ```$summary = podcast_importer_secondline_sanitize_feed_value ( $feed_item_class->current_post_information[ 'post_content' ] );```

and then a function that adds some tags based on the parsing.
But this doesn't seem to work. Any ideas?

Comment: Are you using `wp_set_post_terms` (https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_set_post_terms/)?